# unable to resolve identifier [method] names in C++

Tags: c++, netbeans

So I'm not new to programming, but yeah I'm new to C++. 
I'm getting this error inside the `Next()` method, the `names[]` array is highlighted. Anyone can help?

```
typedef string text;
text Next(text t);
int main() {

text rock;
text names[10] = {"basalt", "dolomite", "granite", "gypsum", "limestone", "marble",
"obsidian", "quartzite", "sandstone", "shale"};
cout<<"Enter a rock: \n";
cin>>rock;
cout<<Next(rock);


return 0;
}

text Next(text t) {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (names[i].compare(t) == 0) {
        return names[i + 1];
    }
}
return "Off boundary or not found";
}
```

Comment: Re-read your book or notes on *variable scopes*

Comment: As @KenWhite suggests, names[] is only available inside main() function. You may either declare the names[] variable at the very top, before the int main() or pass the array as a parameter.

Comment: @DrYunke: The reason I didn't answer directly was because the poster would have learned more by figuring it out.

Comment: I don't believe you. Variable scope isn't unique to C++. You are clearly new to programming.

Comment: What happens if it is the last string from the array, i.e. `names[9].compare(t) == 0`, you will then be trying to return `names[10]` which is not your array. What do you intend to do then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this out, it should hopefully work. I've added some explanation in the last line of code.

```
typedef string text;
text Next(text t, text namesArr[], int size);    // modified

int main() {

    text rock;
    text names[10] = {"basalt", "dolomite", "granite", "gypsum", "limestone", "marble", "obsidian", "quartzite", "sandstone", "shale"};
    cout<<"Enter a rock: \n";
    cin>>rock;
    cout<<Next(rock, names, 10);    // modified

    return 0;
}

text Next(text t, text namesArr[], int size) {    // modified
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (namesArr[i].compare(t) == 0) {
            if (i==9) {
                return namesArr[0]; 
            }
            else {
                return namesArr[i + 1]; 
            }
        }
    }

    return "Not found"; // modified , it should never be out of bound since you specify the fixed array size, and also because you do the checking i==9
}
```

The problem in your code was that you `text names[10]` was defined in you `main()` function. Hence this array is only local to the main function.

If you wanted to use the array in your `Next()` function, you could either

#### 1. Make the `names[]` array global. i.e.

```
typedef string text;
text Next(text t);

// defined globally here, any function can now access this array.
text names[10] = {"basalt", "dolomite", "granite", "gypsum", "limestone", "marble", "obsidian", "quartzite", "sandstone", "shale"};

int main() {
    // your original code here, without the "names[]" declaration.
}

text Next(text t) {
    // your code here, but with the "i==9" case checking to prevent out of bound
}
```

#### 2. Pass the `names[]` array to your functions with the size of the array

This is done in the beginning of my answer

Comment: Thanks man, the second one worked, declaring names[] as global

Comment: oh sorry, see my updated answer, i was passing in `namesArr[]` while still using `names[]` in the `Next()` function. Both should work now.